# How to get tweets with coordinates using twython

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm trying to get tweets here is the geo code

```
    twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

searches = twitter.search_geo(q=keywords, lat = '25.032341', long = '55.385557', count=1, rad = '100mi')
print (searches)
```

getting results not getting tweets

```
{'query': {'type': 'search', 'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/search.json?lat=25.032341&long=55.385557&rad=100mi&q=++-RT&count=1', 'params': {'coordinates': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [55.385557, 25.032341]}, 'trim_place': False, 'query': '', 'autocomplete': False, 'granularity': 'neighborhood', 'accuracy': 0.0}}, 'result': {'places': [{'name': 'Dubai', 'contained_within': [{'name': 'United Arab Emirates', 'place_type': 'country', 'bounding_box': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[51.2938738, 22.6261387], [51.2938738, 26.2823697], [56.3816989, 26.2823697], [56.3816989, 22.6261387], [51.2938738, 22.6261387]]]}, 'full_name': 'United Arab Emirates', 'centroid': [55.147370403855, 24.3556033], 'country': 'United Arab Emirates', 'country_code': 'AE', 'attributes': {}, 'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/3f63906fc8aa5a7d.json', 'id': '3f63906fc8aa5a7d'}], 'place_type': 'admin', 'bounding_box': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[54.8939725, 24.6182526], [54.8939725, 25.3686719], [56.2083722, 25.3686719], [56.2083722, 2
```

Can any one help how I can separate tweets

Comment: You are attempting to use the equivalent of [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/search).  This only finds geolocations near a given longitude and latitude that can be passed as a `place_id` on tweets.  Are you trying to retrieve tweets from a given geolocation?

Answer (score 0):

In [Twython](https://twython.readthedocs.org/), the method `search_geo` is used to find `place_id` for 'places' that are within radius of the provided geolocation.  You need to use the `search` method like so:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError


app_key = 'your_app_key'
app_secret = 'your_app_secret'
oauth_token = 'your_oauth_tokem'
oauth_token_secret = 'your_oauth_secret'

twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

geocode = '25.032341,55.385557,100mi' # latitude,longitude,distance(mi/km)

try:
    searches = twitter.search(count=1, geocode=geocode)
    print(searches)
except TwythonError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: My answer is using a different method than yours (the one that grabs actual tweets and not simply place_ids for nearby points of interest).  The above code does grab the tweets for the specified geocode...